# How many possible combinations? 4 x 4 grid of tiles (with caveats)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, computational-mathematics

I'm designing a board game, the surface of which is made up of 16 tiles, in a grid of 4x4 with 10 unique designs. 6 pairs of these are twins. The user can rotate and also rearrange the tiles and make their own configurations. I got curious about the number of possible permutations. NOTE that 2 of the 16 tiles have a circle design and so have a single state (looks the same when rotated), and one pair has a design that has only 2 states (90 degrees and 180 degrees look exactly like 270 and 360 degrees respectively). All tiles can appear anywhere in the grid. Any chance an equation exists for this or any way to calculate the number of possible permutations? Thanks!

Comment: Are all tiles distinct?

Comment: This caveat doesn't add too much to the complexity, fortunately. If you just forget that two of your tiles are symmetric under rotations and count the number of placements, then you are over-counting by a factor of exactly $4 \times 4 = 16$, i.e. the number of rotations we could apply to those two tiles. If those two tiles are also indistinct (but every other tile is unique), then we are further over-counting by a factor of $2$, as we could swap the two non-unique circle tiles as well.

Comment: Actually, I did not explain that very well. There are technically 10 unique designs. Six of the tiles have identical twins. Of those twins, one pair looks the same in 180 and 360 positions. That takes care of 12 of the tiles. Of the remaining 4 tiles, 1 is a black circle/white ground (has only 1 state) and 1 is white circle green ground (again, 1 state). The remaining two are unique designs. Apologies for the inarticulation. Actually interested in how many permutations are possible given these factors. Thanks to all!

Comment: @JRX This is good information. The last piece of information that would be good to have is whether the board can be rotated. Does the board itself have rotational symmetry? If you pick up and rotate all $16$ tiles as one $4 \times 4$ square by $90$ degrees and place them back down again, is the resulting configuration different or the same?

Comment: The fact that there are 6 identical pairs should be edited into the question, not just left in a comment. Just saying there are 10 unique designs is not specific enough cause the answer would be very different if you had one set of 7 identical tiles rather than 6 pairs.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I did go back and edit - I hope successfully. I Will check again. I don't suppose there is a way to upload an illustration of the tiles. You all will likely see things that I do not. Thanks to all.

Comment: Thank you @TheoBendit. The assumption is that the board itself is static and does not rotate, but that is an interesting question. If I ever get close to an answer on the number of permutations given that, I might add that level of complexity afterwards. Again, very grateful to all here.

Answer (score 0):

How many ways can we place down $16$ unique square tiles onto this grid, ignoring rotations? There are $16! = 20,922,789,888,000$ ways to do this. If we account for repetition of the tiles, there are $6$ pairs of $2$, which can be freely swapped, so $16!$ over-counts by a factor of $2!^6 = 64$. So, still ignoring rotations, there are
$$\frac{16!}{2!^6} = 326,918,592,000$$
possible placements into this grid.

Now, taking into account rotations, $12$ of the tiles have no symmetry whatsoever, and can be rotated independently. Then, two more tiles have $180^\circ$ rotational symmetry. This will add in a factor of $4^{12}\cdot 2^2 = 67,108,864$, This gives us the final count of:
$$\frac{16!}{2!^6} \cdot 4^{12}\cdot 2^2 = 16! \cdot 4^{10} = 21,939,135,329,599,488,000,$$
or just shy of $22$ quintillion possibilities.

Comment: My hero! Thank you so much for this lucid illustration. MANY more than I expected. I was hovering in the quadrillions in my mind. Bless you!